# How to proper install Vitest in Vue 3 app

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vitest

Just installed [Vitest](https://vitest.dev) in my Vue 3 application. The tests are working, but when running `'npm run serve'` I'm getting 29 errors about webpack breaking change:

```
Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/local-pkg/dist/shared.mjs 54:0-49

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/.../node_modules/local-pkg/dist'


ERROR in ./node_modules/local-pkg/index.mjs 1:0-36

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/.../node_modules/local-pkg'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/local-pkg/index.mjs 2:0-47

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/.../node_modules/local-pkg'
```

I tried to add the resolve.fallback, but no luck.
In package.json:

```
"vue": "^3.1.0-0",
"vitest": "^0.14.1",
"happy-dom": "^5.0.0",
"@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.18",
```

Is there a webpack configuration to solve that?

Comment: I do not use Vitest. But as the document points out, it's a framework powered by Vite. So you should use this package with Vite, not Webpack

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue was happening when importing vitest functions inside my tests:

```
// Button.test.js
import { describe } from 'vitest' // <========= this guy
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Component from './Button.vue'

describe('Mount component', () => {
 let wrapper

 it('Should render', () => {
     wrapper = shallowMount(Component)
     expect(wrapper.find('button').exists()).toBeTruthy()
 })
})
```

So, the solution was not to do it.
Vitest has it's config file, where we can set to have those functions enabled globally, so:

```
// vitest.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
const path = require('path')

export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        vue({
            template: {
                compilerOptions: {
                    // treat all tags with a dash as custom elements
                    isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.includes('-'),
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    test: {
        globals: true,  // <========= this guy
        environment: 'happy-dom',
    },
})
```

With that config, I just had to remove all vitest imports (import { describe } from 'vitest' ) from Button.test.js, and the application and tests are working fine.